Кодирование видео
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (vp9 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (vp9 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:2 (opus (native) -> opus (libopus))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x559b204e26c0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x559b204e26c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2 AVX512
[libx264 @ 0x559b204e26c0] profile Main, level 1.2, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x559b204e26c0] 264 - core 163 r3060 5db6aa6 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=2 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=4 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=1 keyint=250 keyint_min=126 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=10 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=150 vbv_bufsize=60 crf_max=0.0 nal_hrd=none filler=0 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[libx264 @ 0x559b204ad940] using SAR=640/639
[libx264 @ 0x559b204ad940] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2 AVX512
[libx264 @ 0x559b204ad940] profile Main, level 2.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x559b204ad940] 264 - core 163 r3060 5db6aa6 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=2 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=1 keyint=250 keyint_min=126 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=10 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=170 vbv_bufsize=80 crf_max=0.0 nal_hrd=none filler=0 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[dash @ 0x559b205078c0] No bit rate set for stream 0
[dash @ 0x559b205078c0] Opening '/var/www/user/data/www/ru/x/init-0.m4s' for writing
[out#0/dash @ 0x559b2049d0c0] Could not write header (incorrect codec parameters ?): No such file or directory
[vf#0:1 @ 0x559b2050cd80] Error sending frames to consumers: No such file or directory
[vf#0:1 @ 0x559b2050cd80] Task finished with error code: -2 (No such file or directory)
[vf#0:1 @ 0x559b2050cd80] Terminating thread with return code -2 (No such file or directory)
[out#0/dash @ 0x559b2049d0c0] Nothing was written into output file, because at least one of its streams received no packets.
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lq=0.0 size=       0KiB time=N/A bitrate=N/A speed=N/A
[libx264 @ 0x559b204e26c0] frame I:1     Avg QP:17.01  size:   291
[libx264 @ 0x559b204e26c0] frame P:7     Avg QP:22.67  size:   544
[libx264 @ 0x559b204e26c0] frame B:9     Avg QP:21.36  size:    27
[libx264 @ 0x559b204e26c0] consecutive B-frames: 11.8% 35.3% 52.9%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x559b204e26c0] mb I  I16..4: 93.1%  0.0%  6.9%
[libx264 @ 0x559b204e26c0] mb P  I16..4: 16.1%  0.0%  2.1%  P16..4: 33.2%  6.8%  2.8%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:39.0%
[libx264 @ 0x559b204e26c0] mb B  I16..4:  0.5%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  5.2%  0.2%  0.0%  direct: 0.7%  skip:93.3%  L0:77.5% L1:21.1% BI: 1.4%
[libx264 @ 0x559b204e26c0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 18.2% 6.9% 0.0% inter: 8.4% 5.8% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x559b204e26c0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 30% 45% 19%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x559b204e26c0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 14% 37% 34%  2%  2%  2%  4%  3%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x559b204e26c0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 91%  8%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x559b204e26c0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:100.0% UV:14.3%
[libx264 @ 0x559b204e26c0] kb/s:61.28
Conversion failed!

Стало выдавать ошибку, после обновления ffmpeg. До этого использовал команду
ffmpeg -i /v.webm -preset veryfast -map_metadata -1\
       -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v main \
       -keyint_min 250 -g 250 -sc_threshold 0 \
       -c:a libopus -b:a 128k -ac 2 -ar 48000 \
       -map v:0 -filter:v:0 "scale=-2:144,fps=30" -minrate:v:0 90k -maxrate:v:0 150k -bufsize:v:0 60k \
       -map v:0 -filter:v:1 "scale=-2:240,fps=30" -minrate:v:1 100k -maxrate:v:1 170k -bufsize:v:1 80k \
       -map 0:a \
       -init_seg_name "init-\$RepresentationID\$.\$ext\$" \
       -media_seg_name "chunk-\$RepresentationID\$-\$Number%05d\$.\$ext\$" \
       -dash_segment_type mp4 \
       -use_template 1 \
       -use_timeline 0 \
       -seg_duration 10 \
       -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a" \
       -f dash \
       /dash.mpd

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем тут ошибка, что та с кодеком. Как ее исправить?

Может у него доступа в папку нет?
